# Typescript type restriction based on another value - how to apply this restriction in an array

Tags: typescript

I wasn't sure how to word this question. I have a scenario where I have an object. Key1 is the name, key2 is options. Options type depends on the value of name.

This works ok, thanks to:

```js
export type Option1 = {
  one: string;
};

export type Option2 = {
  two: string;
};

export type Name = 'first' | 'second';

export type Options<TName extends Name> = TName extends 'first'
  ? Option1
  : TName extends 'second'
  ? Option2
  : never;

type Baz<TName extends Name> = { name: TName, opts: Options<TName> }
```

Now I wish to use this in an object.

```
type MyObj = {
   foo: boolean,
   bar: string,
   baz: Baz[]
}
```

The goal is to do something like this:

```
const test: MyObj = {
   baz: [ { name: 'first': opts: .. }, { name: 'second': opts: .. }]
}
```

With it being all typed correctly. If `name` is 'first', then `opts` is typed to only have key `one`.  However, `MyObj` complains that I need to pass in a generic type to Baz, which makes sense, but I'm not sure what or how. I tried `type Baz<TName extends Name = Name>` to default it, but this just makes all my values a union of all options, where opts is `one` and `two` keys.

How can i restrict this type?

Comment: Is this right? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDyYYEsIDsCMcAvHAN4BQccewAXHAM4xRa4DmA3OQL5fmiRYCZKgzY8AJmJlKCAO4R6TFuy69y5JCjgAhAIYAvaaTi49AWzpwARADMsUJtY7VMDemJwE43OAB8yUwsrawZgAGM8ABNnVxh3dEwvKXVNETgAWUQ0ACMAK2NZWwhFOBySgBtgPVwuKhy9KCVmVk5ZBoN6fQMAbQBdNT5I3CYEYCZ6LNyCkgoqYtLmAFdgABp2xvpra3X6w3oe2SoTM0st+0cYHbiEkxot6x8fXapA05Cw4ZjVm-oTGAUDye3BefXW6iAA

Comment: Ahh so I don't try and be clever with the underlying object, I just create the entire object and union on those. That's a good idea, let me try that in my non-demo codebase.

Comment: Same idea like kennarddh's solution, but more "programmatically": [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDyYYEsIDsCMcAvHAN4BQcVcewAXHAM4xRa4DmA3OQL7fmhIsBMlQZseAEzEylajADuEBs1YdufcgPDR4SFHAByAQwC2qEgHIAZlijNLcAD5xLjYAGM8AE0v9BuiIG4ji4jAA8ACom5gB8MtFmqKAwwLjejK629jCWclQA-OiYofj5cAyJ5nApaRmu7l7pedRwRSFS5Qy4wABuwFD8+qgAQsYAXlExySCp6ZnT8SSkcADaANJwbHBVwAC6DCu4SQzrADQ0mIwMHWHh6-E8cDyru3taw3AAsohoAEYAKxkFFa1ggyjgf3BABtgMZcGdyn9jFAVCw2OxEa1keMGGNJotVu8eFomswEMBmAwfv8gctymCISwAK7ALHUZGorIZSzsqg4hirI4nBqeHy8y4wa5kBBKBgAInlz2exPIQA)

Comment: That's a great way too. Thanks guys, all of these solutions work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it in a very simple way using union type:

```
export type Option1 = {
  one: string;
};

export type Option2 = {
  two: string;
};

export type NameWithOptions =
  | { name: 'first'; opts: Option1[] }
  | { name: 'second'; opts: Option2[] };

type MyObj = {
  foo: boolean;
  bar: string;
  baz: NameWithOptions[];
};

const test: MyObj = {
  baz: [
    { name: 'first', opts: [{ one: 'one' }] },
    { name: 'second', opts: [{ two: 'two' }] },
  ],
};
```

Comment: Yep this worked, I should have known better. Was so focused on the name keys I got tunnelvisioned. Thanks!